# Error Unrecognized character escape (CTRL-CHAR, code 28) in rest assured

Tags: json, rest

I am getting error when i am converting Restassured response to POJO class
Actual response has unicode  `{"value":"\\u001c}`
but when i convert response as string i can see `{ "value": "\"}`

```
ERROR: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized character escape (CTRL-CHAR, code 28)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for an older version of rest assured i.e version 2.9 (com.jayway.restassured)
but i dont know how to handle using newer version of rest assured(3.1 onwards ,io.rest-assured)
i tried below code but its not working

```
 RestAssuredConfig config = RestAssuredConfig.config();
    config = config.encoderConfig(
        config.getEncoderConfig().defaultContentCharset("UTF-8")
            .defaultCharsetForContentType("UTF-8", "application/json"));
    config = config.decoderConfig(
        config.getDecoderConfig().defaultContentCharset("UTF-8")
            .defaultCharsetForContentType("UTF-8", "application/json"));
```

does any one know??